# Copying a json file from one server to another

Tags: json, html

I have an Html page which contains a link to a file with the extension "json.z".

I am trying to copy the json.z file to another location, but every way I use, after changing the link in the html according to the new location, it ends up with the Html file not working any more.

The reference to the file is through:

"pageList":{"masterPage":[" * the url of the json *

the link ends with ".json.z?v=1"

I've tried copying it as a text, downloading it as a "json.z" file,
tried to do it without the "?v=1" and with it in some variations and it just wouldn't work.

What am I missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the server that you're putting it onto serve `.z` files? Perhaps you need to set the mime types on the target server to serve .z as `text/javascript`

You can use Fiddler to see what the server is responding with when you request the file.